# Gatsby develop works but build fails with graphQL warning

Tags: gatsby

I am new to Gatsby so I may be doing something wrong.

I started using a gatsby starter that I modified a bit. Since everything was going smoothly I decided to try making a build... and it failed.

The error says that it could not read a property because it was null. Looking things in more depth I think that the real cause of the error is this warning:

```
    warn The GraphQL query in the non-page component
Exported queries are only executed for Page components. It's possible you're
trying to create pages in your gatsby-node.js and that's failing for some
reason.

If the failing component(s) is a regular component and not intended to be a page
component, you generally want to use a <StaticQuery> (https://gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query)
instead of exporting a page query.

If you're more experienced with GraphQL, you can also export GraphQL
fragments from components and compose the fragments in the Page component
query and pass data down into the child component — http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments
```

I made sure that I am using StaticQuery for non-page components. Also I'm not getting that warning or the error when I do gatsby develop instead of build.

I'm not sure what to do now.
Any advice would be great!